# How to add authenticate header in response in volley Android

Tags: android, api, android-volley

when I hit the api on Postman, it  gives Status :401, 404 etc.
How to get that status in volley response [Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe2Jb.png)

Comment: Click the postman response link to see the status i want to get.

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding getHeaders

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String s) {
    ///handle response from service
}, new ErrorResponse() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    //handle error response
  }
 }) {
  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      //add params <key,value>
      return params;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> headers = Constants.getHeaders(context);
    // add headers <key,value>
    String credentials = USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD;
    String auth = "Basic "
            + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),
            Base64.NO_WRAP);
    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
    return headers;
  }
};
mQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: I think getHeaders is used for the header in the parameters ..not for the header status in response.Am i right or wrong?